# Problem with the formula for generating sides for a right triangle?

Tags: geometry

Everyone knows that in a right triangle, $a = \sqrt x$, $b = \dfrac{x - 1}{2}$, $c = \dfrac{x + 1}{2}$.

Now, consider the triple $48, 55, 73$.

Then, $\sqrt x = \sqrt{48^2}$ since the side has to be $48$ units.

$\sqrt{2304} = 48$.

Therefore, $x = 2304$.

But when we calculate the other sides, it comes out to be $115.2$ and $115.3$.

Without $\sqrt x = 48$, there doesn't seem to be any number fitting into the problem.

Therefore, what value of $x$ should I take to obtain $55$ and $73$?

Thanks,

S Sandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulae you have stated for $a,b,c$ give **some** right triangles but not **all** right triangles.  This should be clear since from your formulae we have $c=b+1$ and so you cannot get $b=55$, $c=73$.  You also can't get, for example, the well-known $(8,15,17)$ triangle, or $(4961,6480,8161)$ which was known to the ancient Babylonians.

To find formulae giving all right triangles with integer sides, look up the topic "Pythagorean triples".

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for a Pythagorean triple is 
\begin{align*}
a & = k(m^2 - n^2)\\
b & = k(2mn)\\
c & = k(m^2 + n^2)
\end{align*}
where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers of different parity (one is even and the other is odd) and $k$ is a positive integer.  When $k = 1$, the numbers in the triple are relatively prime, and it is said to be *primitive*.

The formula you are using corresponds to the special case $k = 1$ and $m = n + 1$.  However, as David pointed out, the Pythagorean triple $(8, 15, 17)$ is not of this form.  It is obtained by setting $m = 4$ and $n = 1$.

Since $\gcd(48, 55, 73) = 1$, this is a primitive Pythagorean triple, so $k = 1$.  Since $48$ is even, set $2mn = 48$, $m^2 - n^2 = 55$, and $73 = m^2 + n^2$ to determine $m$ and $n$.